# Squid caching proxy authentication digest to basic. Is it possible?

Tags: authentication, squid, digest

I need to setup a proxy server connecting to another one with digest auth. I would like that my server takes the credentials from the user using basic scheme and then sending them to the upstream server using digest scheme. It's kinda a "security downgrade". How to achieve that?

Thanks.